# convert multiple values and a key into dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to convert the following data into dictionary, where name is key and all int are values.

- Mary Lee,39,169,100
- James Clark,68,170,105
- Eric Roth,66,161,103
- William Brown,45,180,85

Comment: Which language?. And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Use the name as the key as you said. You should make a tuple of all the numbers and use it for the value.

Answer (score 0):

To create a dictionary in your code, you need the curly brackets `{}`

The general form for declaring a dictionary is

```
{ key1: value1, key2: value2 }
```

Dictionaries only support 1 value for each key. In this case, you want multiple values, so you can use a tuple using the round brackets `()`. A tuple groups multiple values together into single value, which can then be used in the dictionary.

```
{ key1: (v11,v12,v13), key2: (v21,v22,v23) }
```

Using your values, you'd have something like this, I have added line breaks to make it more readable, but these are optional.

```
people = {
    "Mary Lee": (39,169,100),
    "James Clark": (68,170,105),
    "Eric Roth": (66,161,103),
    "William Brown": (45,180,805)
    }
```

If you then wanted to add more values to this dictionary:

```
people["Colin Stevens"] = (55,186,100)
```

However, I would strongly suggest you use python's Object Orientation to give more meaning to these values.

Comment: do you know the code, through which I convert my data in your given format.

Comment: If you're reading the data from a file in the format you specified, then you will need to read and parse the file first - which is a very different question. I would suggest that you ask that separately.